# (Angular 2+) How to get deploy-url after build?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I need to know the build time information(`ng build --this_information` or from `angular.json`), such as `deploy_url` or `base_href` at runtime.

For `base_href`, I can read the `href` attribute of `<base>` tag instead, but there is no any alternative for `deploy_url`.

Can someone give me an "Angular way" to read build configurations at runtime?

## I don't want to change build configurations at runtime, but just want to read and print.

Comment: Do you mean window location? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Comment: what you mean by deploy_url..? normally `build configurations at runtime` is handled in environment.ts files

Comment: No, I mean the arguments in the build command. eg) for the build command `ng build --base_href=/view/ --deploy_url=/lib/`, I want `/view/`, `/lib/`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your build configuration is stored in angular.json, you can copy the bits relevant to you into a json-file in your "src/assets/" folder with the help of a nodeJS script:

```
let fs = require("fs");
let angularJson = require("../angular.json");

let buildConfig = {
  baseHref: angularJson.projects.<projectname>.architect.build.options.baseHref,
  deployUrl: angularJson.projects.<projectname>.architect.build.options.deployUrl,
};

fs.writeFile(
  "./src/assets/buildConfig.json",
  JSON.stringify(buildConfig),
  {flag: ""},
  err => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
);

// example output=> '{"baseHref": "/app", "deployUrl": "https://example.com"}'
```

In this case this script is stored in /scripts, you may need to update your relative paths if you store it in a different folder. Also remember to include the correct projectname. You can include this script before your regular build step by updating the build script in your package.json like this:
`"build": "node ./scripts/extractBuildConfig.js && ng build"`

Although if you only want to get the actual location where a web application is actually deployed, it's probably a lot easier to get the value of `document.location` (or one of its properties), `document.baseURI`, `document.domain` and `document.getElementsByTagName("base")[0].attributes["href"]`.

All that said, if you set up the base href in your Angular project correctly, all relative paths in your files should automatically point to the correct locations, so I'm not sure what you'd even need this for.

Comment: I think this solution is fine because it looks similar with dynamic environments, using `/assets/something.json`. But I wonder if there's any other **Angular Way** (just like `InjectorToken` for `AppModule`, or any Angular predefined constant, etc).

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue too where I needed the `deployUrl` to pass into my `environment.ts` (and `environment.prod.ts`) file during build time. My use case is slightly different where the `deployUrl` is dynamic at
build time. My use case:

- Assets (js, json, css, html, etc) are hosted from my cdn: `https://{cdn}/my-app/{version}/{buildNumber}/...`
- App is *deployed* at my website: `https://app.example.com/`

  - Note: by "deployed", I mean I pull over my `index.html` file from the CDN url – gives me great control over which version & build number gets deployed.

Since my CDN url changes with each build, I cannot use the accepted answer of copying the static configurations from `angular.json`. So my solution takes a few steps but works great for me:

1. Need to set up a custom `webpack.config.js` build configuration. You can follow [Net Basal's article](https://netbasal.com/customize-webpack-configuration-in-your-angular-application-d09683f6bd22) on how to do that.
2. Get my build script setup in `package.json`:

   - `"build:prod": "ng build --prod",`
3. In my build scripts on the server (Jenkins in my case), I make sure to pass the dynamic `deployUrl` to the npm script.

   ```sh
   npm ci && npm run build:prod -- --deployUrl=$CDN_URL && npm test
   ```

   - Note that `$CDN_URL` I dynamically generate during the build process (it matches the CDN pattern I listed above)
4. Add a static string in my `environment.ts` file that webpack will later replace:

   ```js
   declare var __CDN_URL__: string;

   export const environment = {
     production: true,
     deployUrl: __CDN_URL__
   };
   ```
5. Use my `webpack.config.js` to add the `__CDN_URL__` variable to webpack's global scope. Making it available in `environment.ts`

   ```js
   const yargs = require('yargs/yargs')
   const webpack = require('webpack');

   /* parse out the `deployUrl` option passed into our `npm run build:prod` from step #2 */
   const argv = { ...yargs(process.argv).argv };

   /* this config gets merged with Angular's webpack config */
   module.exports = {
     plugins: [
       new webpack.DefinePlugin({
         __CDN_URL__: JSON.stringify(argv.deployUrl || '') // this will add this variable
       })
     ]
   };
   ```

   - Note: I used [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) to parse the `process.argv` options, but you could use anything (or even do it yourself).
   - Docs for [wepack.DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) are kind of lacking, but it essentially creates a variable that you define.

Now you will have access to your dynamic `deployUrl` via your environment config. This worked great for my use case.

I use this for all our assets, but most notable is loading my translation `.json` files. Example:

```js
// app.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    // other imports
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

export function HttpLoaderFactory (http: HttpClient) {
  // this ensures I load my translation files from my cdn url
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, `${environment.deployUrl}i18n/`, '.json');
}
```

Hope this helps someone. Cheers!